# Threads and Semaphores c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I need to write simplyfied Worker class, which contains non-static methods `start` - starts the thread, `run` - main thread function, `join` - waits for terminating, `wait` - waits for notification and `notify` - sends the notification. So, the question is: how can I notify the thread with number 1, 2 and ect? Because I know, that threads have such methods as `notify_all()` an `notify_one()`, but the former notifies all threads and the latter unblocks one of the threads (but not with exact number) currently waiting for the condition.

Comment: Notifying condition variable implies that threads, waiting on it, have *no preferrable awaken order*. If the order is meaningfull for your case, you need to use different condition variables for different threads. Or use technique different from condition variables.

Comment: @Tsyvarev  Thanks a lot :)